# How can I change permissions for a folder and all sub files and folders in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

how can someone set permissions on a folder so that they themselves, but noone else, can delete folders or files within that folder on a shared network drive? this is a windows 7 question.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to give your account explicit MODIFY permission at the top level\parent folder and then give the others READ access at that same top level folder and let that inherit down implicitly to all files and subfolders beneath. You'll run into all sorts of issues allowing people to create files and folders but restricting delete permissions as some apps create temp files, and with the delete permissions restricted with them being allowed to create files and cause issues.

Comment: PIMP, is there any way you could post screen shots of the windows? Thanks

Comment: I cannot add an answer to this question since it was marked as a duplicate. I'd start a new question asking for an answer with screen shots of how to configure a network share so that it'll suit your needs. Perhaps with little searching on this site with the Search function, you might find an answer with applicable detail already exists and you can use it and then give such an answer an upvote for the work.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the permissions (Right-click -> Properties -> Security) and remove the Delete permissions on both files **and** folders. Then make sure you enable permissions inheritance before you confirm the edits.